# Second order linear recurrence for matrices

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations

Say, I have the following recurrence relation with $\hat{A}, ~\hat{B}$ known square matrices of complex numbers.

$$\begin{cases}\hat{W}^{(0)}=1 \\ \hat{W}^{(1)}=-\hat{A} \\ \hat{W}^{(n+2)}=-\hat{A}\hat{W}^{(n+1)}-\hat{B}\hat{W}^{(n)} \end{cases}$$

The corresponding recurrence for numbers has a simple closed form solution, which could be found by solving a quadratic:

$$x^2+ax+b=0$$

Then the general solution can be expressed as $C_1 x_1^n+C_2 x_2^n$.

However, I believe for matrices (which may not commute) the solution is not as simple. Could you point me in the right direction?

---

While the question is general enough, if you are curious about my motivation, I have been trying to invent a new perturbation method for time dependent Schroedinger equation, and obtaining an explicit solution for this recurrence would make my life easier.

---

Googling "matrix linear recurrence" has produced very little in the way of general results and nothing for second order recurrences...

Comment: Suppose the matrices have size $d \times d$. Then isn’t this second-order matrix recurrence equivalent to a $2d$-order linear recurrence, where we replace each matrix equation with $d$ equations in the columns of $W$?

Comment: @Joppy, technically yes, but wouldn't it make the problem more complicated and more computationally involved? At least there are algorithms for matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Partial answer, too long for a comment*.) An explicit form can be found in case there exists an *invertible* matrix $\,C\,$ that satisfies the quadratic $\,C^2-CA+B=0\,$ *and* commutes with $\,B\,$.

Multiplying the recurrence by $\,C\,$ gives:

$$
C\,W_{n+2}=-\underbrace{\,CA\,}_{C^2+B}W_{n+1}-CB\,W_{n} \;\; \iff \;\; C\,(W_{n+2}+ C\, W_{n+1}) = -B\,(W_{n+1}+C\,W_{n})
$$

It follows that:

$$
W_{n+2}+ C\, W_{n+1} = -C^{-1}B\,(W_{n+1}+C\,W_{n}) = \ldots = \left(-C^{-1}B\right)^{n+1} \,(W_1 + C\,W_0)
$$

This reduces the problem to a first order linear recurrence of the form $\,Z_{n+1}=U\,Z_n+V^n\,W\,$ where $\,U=-C\,$ and $\,V = -C^{-1}B\,$, which telescopes to:

$$
Z_{n+1}=U^{n+1}\,Z_0 + \left(V^n + V^{n-1} \, U+ \ldots + V\,U^{n-1}+ U^n\right)\,W
$$

In the case where $\,V-U\,$ is invertible, and given that $\,U,V\,$ commute, this further simplifies to:

$$
Z_{n+1} = U^{n+1}\,Z_0+ \left(V-U\right)^{-1}\,\left(V^{n+1}-U^{n+1}\right)\,W
$$

Comment: Thank you! I wish I had any idea if these conditions are satisfied in the general case of my problem, but I will check experimentally

Comment: @YuriyS Glad it helped. FWIW if $B$ is also invertible, then $C^{-1}B$ is another root of $X^2-XA+B=0$, so the end result resembles the real case fairly closely. The other question, however, is how computationally easy/convenient such approach would be.